# On relationships between the general terms of sequences from different equivalences to the Riemann Hypothesis

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

The following are simple deductions using easy calculations for inequalities and limits.

I define the following sequences, whose shape is inspired in **Nicolas, Robin** and **Lagarias**, respectively, equivalences for the Riemann Hypothesis (see below the reference for each one) for $n\geq 5041$

**Robin's sequence** is defined as $$\mathcal{R}_n:=\frac{\sigma(n)}{n\log\log n},$$ where $\sigma(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}d$ is the **sum of divisors function**;

**Lagarias sequence** is defined by $$\mathcal{L}_n:=\frac{e^{\sigma(n)}}{n\left(H_n\right)^{e^{H_n}}},$$
where $H_n=1+1/2+\cdots+1/n$ is the nth **harmonic number**;

and **Nicolas sequence** is defined (**here there was a mistake/typo that was fixed**) as $$\mathcal{N}_n:=\frac{N(n)}{\phi(N(n))}\frac{1}{\log\log N(n)},$$
where $\phi(m)$ is the **Euler's totient function**, and the arithmetic function $N(n)=\prod_{k=1}^n p_k$ is defined to be **the product of the first** $n$ **primes.**

> **Claim 1.** On assumption of **the Riemann hypothesis** thus it is possible to write that $$\mathcal{R_n}<e^{\gamma}<\mathcal{N_n},$$
>   **for** $n>5040$.

It is possible to show, if my calculations were right, (you are welcome to ask in comments about them, if you want; I've used  $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sigma(n)-\log n-e^{H_n}\log H_n\leq \gamma\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\log(\mathcal{N}_n)$, and after I take the exponential)

> **Claim 2.** On assumption of the Riemann hypothesis
>   $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\mathcal{L}_n\leq \lim_{n\to \infty}\mathcal{N}_n.$$

I've used **Gronwall's Theorem** to deduce

> **Claim 3.** On assumption of the Riemann hypothesis one has
>   $$\gamma<\limsup_{n\to\infty}\mathcal{N}_n\frac{\log H_n}{\log(\log H_n)}.$$

My question if that if it possible state relationships between the general term of such sequences:

> **Question.** It is known (in such case reference it) or can you deduce if on assumption of the Riemann hypothesis is there an integer $N>5040$ such that for $n\geq N$ one has the relationship $$\mathcal{R}_n\leq\mathcal{L}_n\leq \mathcal{N}_n?$$
>   If previous relationship is wrong, what is the first counterexample? **Thanks in advance.**

---

**Appendix: (A remark, and the references of the cited papers for previous equivalences):** The remark is that it is possible write this kind of relationships for arithmetics functions from different equivalences, for example one that involves the **least common multiple**, if one define $\text{Num}(n)$ by $$H_n=\frac{\text{Num}(n)}{\text{l.c.m}(1,2,\ldots,n)}$$ (I don't write the reference because I don't write such equivalence).

Previous references to justify the shape of the sequences that I've typed were

G. ROBIN, Grandes valeurs de la fonction somme des diviseurs et hypothése de Riemann, **J. Math. Pures Appl.** (9) 63 (1984), 187-213.

J. NICOLAS, Petites valeurs de la fonction d'Euler, **J. Number Theory** 17 (1983), 375-388.

J.C. LAGARIAS, An elementary problem equivalent to the Riemann Hypothesis, **Amer. Math. Monthly** 109 (2002), 534-543.

Comment: For **Claim 3.** I've deduced $$e^{H_n}\log(H_n)<\frac{N(n)}{\phi(N(n))}ne^{-O(1/n)}\frac{\log H_n}{\log(\log H_n)},$$ and after I've applied Gronwall's Theorem.

Comment: Can you write all the steps for showing how RH is implied/equivalent to $R_n < e^{\gamma}$ for $n$ large enough ? (I think the $\implies$ part is not very complicated)

Comment: I'm searching for proofs of that, but I didn't find any yet

Comment: I'm sorry @user1952009 **there was a great mistake/typo, that I've fixed, Nicolas sequence is  $\mathcal{N}_n:=\frac{N(n)}{\phi(N(n))}\frac{1}{\log\log N(n)}.$ Then **Claim 1** is obvious, that is the conjunction of Nicolas and Robin equivalences. **Claim 2** follows from a similar comparison between Lagarias and Nicolas: from $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sigma(n)-\log n-e^{H_n}\log H_n\leq \gamma\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\log(\mathcal{N}_n)$ then we will take exponentials for $\log\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathcal{L}_n \leq \log\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathcal{N}_n$. Now I am thinking what was about the third claim.

Comment: Truly, today, I don't know how obtain **Claim 3**, but my first comment should be useful. In the other hand $\mathcal{R}_n < e^{\gamma}$ is Robin equivalence, thus aren't necessary more calculations to show that RH if and only if previous inequality  $\mathcal{R}_n < e^{\gamma}$. After I delete this comment, my apologizes by a post with confused definitions. When I have the proof of third claim I add it @user1952009 Merci

Comment: I think the interesting part is to prove $R_n <e^\gamma \implies $ RH,  once you got it, the rest should follow easily. $\ \ $ Tks to [will Jagy](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/10400/will-jagy) there is the original Robin paper, and 3 others that should help you (us)  : http://www.paris8.free.fr/Zeta_Riemann/RobinCriterion/

Comment: You are welcome, very thanks much to you and Will Jagy, by the paper, should help to you, I am not a professional. Merci @user1952009